# MvvmLight IDataService with async await

Tags: c#-4.0, mvvm-light, async-await

I'm trying to find a clean way to accomplish MvvmLight's IDataService pattern with async/await.

Originally I was using the callback Action method to work similar to the template's but that doesn't update the UI either.

```
public interface IDataService
{
    void GetData(Action<DataItem, Exception> callback);
    void GetLocationAsync(Action<Geoposition, Exception> callback);
}

public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public void GetData(Action<DataItem, Exception> callback)
    {
        // Use this to connect to the actual data service

        var item = new DataItem("Location App");
        callback(item, null);
    }

    public async void GetLocationAsync(Action<Geoposition, Exception> callback)
    {
        Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator locator = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();
        var location = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        callback(location, null);
    }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;

    private string _locationString = string.Empty;
    public string LocationString
    {
        get
        {
            return _locationString;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_locationString == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _locationString = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(LocationString);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        _dataService.GetLocation(
            (location, error) =>
            {
                LocationString = string.Format("({0}, {1})",
                location.Coordinate.Latitude,
                location.Coordinate.Longitude);
            });
    }
}
```

**I'm trying to databind against gps coordinates but since the async fires and doesn't run on main thread it doesn't update the UI.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be unrelated, but AFAICT you're missing some quotes

```
        RaisePropertyChanged(LocationString);
```

You pass the name of the property that changed, not its value.

Comment: AFAICT you're calling the protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) in ObservableObject.  Did you mean to call the Expression version and pass () => LocationString or similar? http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b922e8ccf674#GalaSoft.MvvmLight%2fGalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29%2fObservableObject.cs

Comment: @jeremy James is right. If you are trying raise the PropertyChanged event on your LocationString property, then you must call the method like this                              `RaisePropertyChanged("LocationString")` or if you want to avoid typing strings then like this `var expression = () => LocationString;` `RaisePropertyChanged(expression.Member.Name)`

Comment: The magic of MvvmLight still requires you to use `RaisePropertyChanged(() => LocationString);`. As your code stands you're passing the _current value of_ `LocationString` to the RaisePropertyChanged method.